# Wordpress/OpenLiteSpeed Cannot Publish

Tags: wordpress, permalinks, litespeed

My server is Ubtuntu 18.04, OpenLiteSpeed, and Wordpress. With all plugins disabled, and using the default theme we are unable to publish or update posts/pages. This question looks similar to a lot of other ones but none of their solutions are working for me. My understanding of this issue is that maybe our htaccess file isn't being respected by OpenLiteSpeed, even though it is configured to do so. I have not edited the .htaccess file at all. Here are its contents:

```
# BEGIN LSCACHE
# END LSCACHE
# BEGIN NON_LSCACHE
# END NON_LSCACHE

### Forcing HTTPS rule start       
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
### Forcing HTTPS rule end

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I also get 404 error messages in the console for urls in this path: https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/*

I have tried updating the permalink structure multiple times to no avail, unless I add index.php to the structure. For example `https://example.com/index.php/%postname%/`. This allows us to visit posts, update them, etc.

It's great that we can have it working, but that index.php in the URL is just so darn ugly. What do I need to do to get rid of it?

Comment: Those rules should works on openlitespeed which I just tested. You can remove it see if it makes any different. I also checked XXXXX/wp-json/wp/v2 request returns 200 instead of 404. Any other step to reproduce the issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using rewriterule tab in webadmin console, instead of .htaccess

you will need to change the rule

from

`RewriteRule ^index.php$ - [L]`

to

`RewriteRule ^/index.php$ - [L]`

save and restart it.

there is slightly [difference](https://openlitespeed.org/kb/migrate-apache-rewrite-rules-to-openlitespeed/) for rewrite rule when you place it in different place, mostly a forwarding slash like above one.

Comment: Naw I am using the .htaccess file that is in the root of the wordpress folder on the server.

Comment: I tried placing the rewrite rules in the webadmin console, and after restarting still no luck.

Comment: if you are using .htaccess, did you enable "autoload .htaccess"  ?  with htaccess, you need to remove /  , if you are using webadmin console , you need to attach /